# MQTT receive messages in multiples on page refresh

Tags: node.js, socket.io, mqtt

I have a node.js server running with an express webpage on the front end. I am using socket.io to communicate between my webpage and index.js so that the webpage will automatically update upon receiving a message. I am new to javascript and node in general and will try to explain this as best I can.

I have tried to isolate the problem as much as possible. The webpage does not display anything as of right now, but upon connection to the node server it will send the topic to subscribe to over socket.io

This is my index.js code

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var mqtt = require('mqtt');
var broker = 'mqtt:localhost'
var mqtt_client = mqtt.connect(broker);
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){

    // Client Connects prints this
    console.log('a user connected');

    // Client disconnects prints this
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
      console.log('user disconnected');
      mqtt_client.unsubscribe("bedroom/lights");
    });

    // When Client emits to subscribe
    socket.on("subscribe", (data) => {
      console.log("Subscribe > topic: " + data.topic);
      // MQTT subscribe broker topic
      mqtt_client.subscribe(data.topic);
    });

    // When Client emits to publish 
    socket.on("publish", (data) => {
      console.log("Publish > topic: " + data.topic + ", message: " + data.message);
      // MQTT publish to broker 
      mqtt_client.publish(data.topic, data.message, { qos: 0, retain: false });
    });

    // When MQTT receives a message
    mqtt_client.on("message", (topic, message, packet) => {
      console.log('received message %s %s', topic, message)

    });

  });

http.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('listening on *:' + port);
});
```

my app.js file that is run when the webpage is loaded has this code

```
(document).ready(function () {
    var socket = io();
    socket.on("connect", () => {
        console.log("Connected to server!!!");
        socket.emit("subscribe", { topic: "#" });
        socket.emit("publish", { topic: "bedroom/client/connection", message: "Client Connected" });
    });
});
```

This code works great initially, I get this output:

```
> node index.js

listening on *:3000
a user connected
Subscribe > topic: #
Publish > topic: bedroom/client/connection, message: Client Connected
received message bedroom/client/connection Client Connected
```

but if I refresh the page, I get:

```
user disconnected
a user connected
Subscribe > topic: #
Publish > topic: bedroom/client/connection, message: Client Connected
received message bedroom/client/connection Client Connected
received message bedroom/client/connection Client Connected
```

I seem to receive multiple messages, and if I refresh the page again there will be a third received message item. I have another separate program running that subscribes to all the mqtt broker topics and prints their messages. Interestingly, the node program still sends individual messages to the broker, but the receiving aspect prints a multiple depending on how many times I refresh the page. Any help in fixing this would be awesome.

Comment: Why not remove the socket.io and just subscribe directly to the broker with MQTT over Websockets from within the webpage?

Comment: Also you are subscribing to '#' and unsubscribing from `bedroom/lights`. Why  the miss match?

Comment: the wild card subscribe is just an easy way I was using to see all the messages, it would normally be bedroom/lights, i missed changing that part back before the post. Also I'm using socket.io because I want to eventually start storing the values into a database to create graphs that show something like light usage etc. If you think this can still be done over websockets I'd be happy to look into it. Thank you for the suggestions!